# navigation view doesn't work first click

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode4

I have a navigation view, when I click, I just show the row number.

In the mainView:

```
-(void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

if (read == nil) {
    readNotice *aController = [[readNotice alloc]initWithNibName:@"readNotice" bundle:nil];
    self.read = aController;   
}

[read updateRowNumber:indexPath.row];

[[self navigationController] pushViewController:read animated:YES];
```

and in my `readNotice` class:

```
-(void)updateRowNumber:(int)theindex {

rowNumber = theindex + 1;

message.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"row %i was clicked", rowNumber];

NSLog(@"view did load row = %d", rowNumber);

}
```

readNotice.xib only contents a Label.

First time I click it shows "Label", but it works the following tries.

I suppose I need to initiliaze something that I missed, but I cant find it.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Is new view controller  open or not When you click on cell?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I m not able to understand why you made read variable .... ? use this ..

```
-(void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

  readNotice *aController = [[readNotice alloc]initWithNibName:@"readNotice" bundle:nil];
  [self.navigationController pushViewController:aController  animated:YES];
  [aController updateRowNumber:indexPath.row];
}
```

may this will help you...

Answer (score 0):

Use -

```
if (self.read == nil) {
    readNotice *aController = [[readNotice alloc]initWithNibName:@"readNotice" bundle:nil];
    self.read = aController;   

}
--------
---------

[[self navigationController] pushViewController:self.read animated:YES];
```

Comment: i have only suggested to use use proper view controller, rest code which is required needs to be in place.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,
in tableview:didSelectRowAtIndex method,

```
 -(void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

 if (read == nil) {
    readNotice *aController = [[readNotice alloc]initWithNibName:@"readNotice" bundle:nil];
    self.read = aController;   
 }

 read.index = indexPath.row;
 [[self navigationController] pushViewController:read animated:YES];
```

create a instance variable in `readNotice` as

```
     @property(assign) int index;

     @synthesize index;
```

In `readNotice` viewDidLoad method, you just call `updateRowNumber`

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad 
 {
   [super viewDidLoad];
   [self updateRowNumber:index];
 }
```

It will display the number as you expected